# Swift: Deselect UITextField

Tags: swift

is it possible to deselect a UITextfield programmatically?

I have several textfields with a pickerView as input instead of the keyboard. But when I click on a cancel button I want to deselect the current textfield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder)

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

> Notifies the receiver that it has been asked to relinquish its status
>   as first responder in its window.
>
> Discussion The default implementation returns YES, resigning first
>   responder status. Subclasses can override this method to update state
>   or perform some action such as unhighlighting the selection, or to
>   return NO, refusing to relinquish first responder status. If you
>   override this method, you must call super (the superclass
>   implementation) at some point in your code.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

[`func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder)

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

> Notifies the receiver that it is about to become first responder in
>   its window.
>
> Return Value YES if the receiver accepts first-responder status or NO
>   if it refuses this status. The default implementation returns YES,
>   accepting first responder status.
>
> Discussion Subclasses can override this method to update state or
>   perform some action such as highlighting the selection.
>
> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder)
>   and the new responder can become first responder.
>
> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the
>   first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if it
>   is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it
>   returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.